# Probability - conditional probability on student passing

Tags: probability

The chance of a student passing an exam is 20%. The chance of a student passing the exam and getting above 90% marks in it is 5%. Given that a student passes the examination, the probability that the student gets above 90% marks is ____.

Answer is: $\frac{1}{4}$

I still didn't understand the solution clearly. I noticed word **given** and identified it must be related to conditional probability, and found answer. but when I re-read the question they were asking probability of student passes and he gets 90% marks is ___ and they have already mentioned probability if student passes the exam and gets more 90% marks is 5%. i.e. 0.05. Now I am confused both statement seems exactly the same.

I tried to relate with an example as well.

first line meaning: if there are 100 students then 20 student passes. 
second line meaning: now out of 100 only 5% of them pass and get more than 90% so out of 5 students gets more than 90%.

Question asks: given that student passes the examination, means now I have a set of 20 students. 
Now I need to find probability of out of 20 passing student number of students scored more than 90% marks. so I don't know out of 20 how many of them have got more than 90% marks but I do know out of 100 students there are only 5 of them have got more than 90% marks and they must have been included in those 20 people.

Hence the overall probability becomes = $\frac{no. \ of \ student \ scored \ more \ than\ 90\%}{total \ passing \ students}$ = $\frac{5}{20}$ = $\frac{1}{4}$.

Is my above logic in example is correct?

Comment: I used the conditional probability formula: P(A|B) = $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ to find the answer, but I wanted to know whether my concept is correct or not and hence I considered above example

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: I often think of conditional probability in terms like you did. Note that at the point where you said that all of the $5$ students with high marks must be among the $20$ who passed, you implicitly said that in this particular problem, $P(A\cap B)=P(A).$

Comment: The conditional statement limits you to just looking at the 20% who passed the exam. Of those, 1/4 (5% of the total) got above 90%.

Comment: @ Phil H Now I understood perspective of conditional probability. @ David K yes true. Thank you @user247327